# dropdownlist box not passing the selected text in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to create a webform with a drop down list box in which the items are populated dynamically, when the form is loaded, I want to pass the text selected by the user to another page.
but the first value in the drop down list box is getting passed irrespective of the selected text.
how do i pass the value selected by the user?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try to search for solution on web?

Answer (score 1):

U can use **DropDownList.SelectedValue**  to get the value selected from the dropdown

and u can take reference from this link for further detail

http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t98693-how-to-get-selected-value-from-dropdown-list.html

Answer (score 1):

I think the error goes on the binding. On your page load do you add this code?

```
Protected Sub Page_load (...)
 if ispostback="false" then
 //Bind here....
 end if
End Sub
```

or try setting the Autopostback of your dropdown to true
and try dropdownlist.text (for text) or dropdown.selectedvalue(for value)